# Flutter TabBarView and Tabs

Tags: flutter, title, tabbar

I have a strange issue with my TabBarView and Tabs and that is that appBar title of first screen appears on other screen when using TabBarView. I only want appBar title from screen1 to be on screen1 and appBar title in screen2 be on screen2. Screen1 and Screen2 are same.
How do I fix this error?

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TabBarDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabBarDemoState createState() => _TabBarDemoState();
}

class _TabBarDemoState extends State<TabBarDemo>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
 TabController tabController;
  List<Tab> tabBars;
  List<Widget> tabBarViews;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
     tabBars = [
      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 34), text: 'Hem',),
      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 34), text: 'Sök',),
      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings, size: 34), text: 'Inställningar'),
    ];
    tabBarViews = [welcomeLayout(context),Screen1(),Screen2()];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: ColorStyle.black,
        elevation: 0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('Home Screen'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
       body: TabBarView(
          children: tabBarViews,
          controller: tabController,
        ),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(controller: tabController, tabs: tabBars,
        labelColor: ColorStyle.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {  
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: ColorStyle.black,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text('First Screen'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      backgroundColor: ColorStyle.black,
      body: Container()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually its not the appbar of first screen being shown. It is the one that you have mentioned in your TabBarDemo. So to get rid of it remove it from their i.e.-

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       //removed appBar
       body: TabBarView(
          children: tabBarViews,
          controller: tabController,
        ),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(controller: tabController, tabs: tabBars,
        labelColor: ColorStyle.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and if you want to show it in your welcomeLayout then make it a scaffold widget and show appbar over there.

Comment: Well,  it is appBar title from TabBarDemo that appears on Screen1 and welcomeLayOut is only a stack with some children widgets. AppBar title from Screen1 is also displayed under title from TabBarDemo.

Comment: If you don't want the same appbar on all pages then remove it as shown in the code and add appbar to each page individually. And for that in welcomeLayout wrap the stack as the body of a scaffold.